# AngularJS : filter item in ng-repeat without using filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to filter my item store in database, but I don't want to use filter like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { etat: 'enCours' } ">
```

This line filter all the posts where etat = 'enCours',  but this cause me several problem cause I have several ng-repeat and I can't use $index.

I would like to do something like this :

```
<li ng-repeat="post in postsEnCours">
```

With using this function :

```
This line give me all the post store in my database
$scope.posts= Posts.query();

$scope.postsEnCours = $scope.posts.filter(function(item, index) {
    return item.etat === 'enCours';
})
```

But nothing appears do you know why ?

Comment: Is your Posts.query function synchronous? If it is not; then you should filter after query is done.

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem but I don't know how to tell to the function to wait until the query is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be depended on `ng-repeat`'s `$index` .

If you use isolate directive or directive with `scope : true` in `ng-repeat`, you won't find `$index` correctly.

`Posts.query()` may have callback.  If it has callback then you have to put your filter inside it's callback's method.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I find this on web :
`Item.query({}, function() {
//you callback
});`

If I place my filter inside this is it working ?

Comment: yap put inside that callback @VaudeyBaptiste